# CASE statement inside OR inside AND in SQL

Tags: sql, nested, case, case-when

```
RES as 
(
SELECT code , payement,
sum(A.ALLPAYMENT) as ACTUAL_PAYMENT,
A.NAME
FROM FINANCES A 
WHERE payement= '6396'   
and (ENDDATE>=  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
and (BILLREFRENCE<> '' or 

(case when (    CONVERT (int, (select BILLTIME from MYCALENDAR CL
                                where CL.code = A.code and CL.NAME= 
A.NAME
                              )  
                         )
               > CONVERT (INT, REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108), 
               ':', '' ) )  
            ) then LEVEL in ('300', '100', '404')
              else
                LEVEL in ('300','404')
)


 )
GROUP BY code, payement, A.NAME)
```

the OR condition needs to be either " OR LEVEL in ('300', '100', '404') " or
 " OR LEVEL in ('300', '404') "
if the current systemtime is greater than the BILLTIME  it's LEVEL in ('300','404') if not, it's  LEVEL in ('300', '100', '404')

PS : BILLTIME is in the format of military time "130000", hence the conversions.

Comment: Don't use `case` in `where` clauses. It can be rewritten in simple boolean logic.

Comment: CASE is not (part of) a statement, but a conditional `EXPRESSION` ( just like the ternary expression in C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the result of an expression inside `WHERE` clause is boolean, you can always rewrite it as a boolean expression without using a `CASE` expression. In some cases, the logic can be simplified, too.

Since the `IN` list from the first case differs from the `IN` list in the second case by only one member, `'100'`, you can restructure your condition to avoid `IN` list inside a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    ...
WHERE LEVEL in ('300','404')
   OR LEVEL = '100' AND CONVERT(...) > CONVERT(...)
```

Comment: duh ! this worked , I dont know how I couldnt see that. Thank you very much :)